# What visual artifacts are expected from the JWST?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, space-telescope, james-webb-space-telescope

What visual artifacts should we expect from the images that will be released from the James Webb Space Telescope? Specifically, do we expect 3-pronged diffraction spikes (any preview how they would look?)? Do we expect any artifacts due to the honeycomb-like structure of the main mirror?

Comment: There won't be only mirror-like artifacts like A. Leistra stated, but additional every instrument will have their own artifacts, e.e. due to imperfect correction from flatfields, and also depending on the filterwheels/gratings used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JWST images will have various artifacts. I found a [web page](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-imager-and-slitless-spectrograph/niriss-predicted-performance/niriss-point-spread-functions) that summarises the situation for the [Near Infrared Imager and Slitless Spectrograph](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-imager-and-slitless-spectrograph/niriss-observing-modes/niriss-imaging) (NIRISS).

The image below (taken from that webpage) shows simulated point sources as they would appear on the detector (including the sampling by the 0.0656 arcsec pixels). The greyscale is on a logarithmic scale of brightness. Each postage stamp corresponds a 77x77 pixel region around the point source, imaged through [filters](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-imager-and-slitless-spectrograph/niriss-instrumentation/niriss-filters) at different wavelengths (identified by the code in the top left, where 090 corresponds to 0.9 $\mu$m etc. and the W or M corresponds to wide-band or medium-band).

*NIRISS simulated PSFs, with 0.0656 arcsec pixels*
[image: JWST NIRISS PSFs]

Then there is a [further web page](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-camera/nircam-predicted-performance/nircam-point-spread-functions) that gives the equivalent information for [Near Infrared Camera](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/near-infrared-camera) (NIRCam), which has a short-wavelength (SW) and long-wavelength (LW) channel, as well as several filters associated with each of these.

*NIRCam SW simulated PSFs, with 0.031 arcsec pixels*
[image: NIRCam SW PSFs]

*NIRCam LW simulated PSFs, with 0.063 arcsec pixels*
[image: NIRCam LW PSFs]

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking about the PSF (point-spread function)?

There are some simulations & basic images available as well as a downloadable package you can use to compute the PSF for a particular instrument and wavelength.  Since the telescope hasn't been fully assembled yet these are based on simulations.

- https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/science-planning/proposal-planning-toolbox/psf-simulation-tool
- https://stsci.app.box.com/v/jwst-simulated-psf-library